# homestead machine is running but urls not found

Tags: laravel, virtualbox, homestead

I am using homestead and it is my first time. now i can run the homestead up and machine starts.
i edited the `homestead.yaml` file and i edited hosts file but when i try to go to my website in the browser it says that the webpage is not available.
for more information i am using windows and virtual box and here is my hosts file

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.10.10   exam.dev
```

i am wondering what can i do to fix this problem. what i am missing here?

Edit: i tried to ping the 192.168.10.10 but it says that destination host is unreachable